# Angular: hide errors on input focus

Tags: validation, angularjs

I am looking for a global way to hide validation errors when an input is focused.
It has to work with code similar to [the following](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1lPBCKXcNNyGOSwH2Yo?p=preview), without changes to the markup:

```
<form name="sampleForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="sampleField" data-ng-model="exForm.exField" data-ng-minlength="10">
  <div data-ng-show="sampleForm.sampleField.$dirty">
    <span data-ng-show="sampleForm.sampleField.$error.minlength">
          At least 10 characters
      </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

I *believe* I could set the input as pristine everytime the user interacts with it:

```
$scope.sampleForm.sampleField.$setPristine();
```

but I'm not sure how I could attach a global focus handler that does it for every input/select etc.
Validation should still happen on blur.

Is it possible to do the above, or is there a better option?

Comment: Have you tried with novalidate in the form tag ?

Comment: @Whisher I believe that's unrelated, but I'll add `novalidate`